# Using map in scheme, a strange thing happens when I use the display function

Tags: dictionary, scheme, void, r5rs

in scheme (I'm using racket R5RS) when I call this procedure

```
(map display '(1 2 3 4 5))
```

it returns

```
12345(#<void> #<void> #<void> #<void> #<void>)
```

Why is that? What's up with the void?

Comment: You have another question to close: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16733472/1286639

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said:

"it returns `12345(#<void> #<void> #<void> #<void> #<void>)`"

which isn't precisely correct.  That is what it **prints/displays**; not what it **returns**.  You get the return value with:

```
> (define test (map display '(1 2 3 4 5)))
12345> test
(#<void> #<void> #<void> #<void> #<void>)
>
```

Here it is clearer: '12345' was printed; the return value, bound to `test`, is your 'void' list.

The reason for the 'void' values is that `map` applies its function to each element in the list and constructs a new list with the value returned by function.  For `display` the return value is 'void'.  As such:

```
> (define test2 (display 1))
1> (list test2)
(#<void>)
>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `for-each` instead of `map`, in your case. `for-each` is non-collecting, unlike `map`.

Also, `for-each` is guaranteed to pass the list items from left to right to your function. `map` makes no such guarantee, and is allowed to pass the list items in any order. (Although, in the specific case of Racket, `map` does use a left-to-right order. But you cannot depend on this in other Scheme implementations; some use a right-to-left order, and theoretically, other orderings are possible.)

Answer (score 0):

[`map`](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%_idx_558) collects the results of each invocation of the function on each element of the list and returns the list of these results.

[`display`](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%_idx_624) returns an unspecified value. `#<void>` is just something that Racket is using. It could have returned 42 as well.

You probably have a typo. It should have returned

```
12345(#<void> #<void> #<void> #<void> #<void>)
```

without the leading open parenthesis. I.e. the five values are isplayed, and then the return value.

Comment: But map sends each element of a list to display, which then should not return anything. How would I get display to return void in racket myself? And you are right, the leading open parenthesis is a typo, will fix it. Thanks!

Comment: @HatoriSanso you can read the specs at the link that I provided. It says "returns unspecified value". I.e. `display` indeed returns some value - to the function that called it. That at the same time some output also appeared at some console window, is just another part of its operation. You see it because you call it at the REPL, which also prints the last returned value.