# Set! in Scheme not behaving correctly

Tags: scheme, racket, priority-queue

So I'm trying to create a priority queue in Scheme and the implementation I have uses the set! function.

```
;Priotiy Queue   
(define (create-queue) '())

(define  (addq! q obj)
    (if (or (null? q) (< obj (car q)))
        (set! q (cons obj q))
        (set! q (cons (car q) (addq! q obj)))))

(define getq!
  (lambda (q)
    (car q)))

(define remq!
  (lambda (q)
    (set! q (cdr q))))
```

The `addq!`function at the moment doesn't work and when called doesn't add anything to a queue. It seems like the `set!`function isn't actually changing the value of the queue it's being called on. I've looked at lot at documentation on `set!`and this seems to be the correct way of using it. I feel like it's some obvious thing that I'm missing.

Comment: please *show us the code* that you run to create your queue, add to the queue, and print out the result afterwards.

Comment: No 'hanging parens' please.

Comment: While this isn't a duplicate of it, you might be interested in taking a look at [How is set! defined in scheme?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16733472/1281433) The accepted answer describes how you can implement `set-car!`-like functions for structures based on lexical closures.  In your case, you want `remq!` function for something that's not a lexical closure, but the answer there might provide some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers have explained the problem very well. I want to present you a solution that works as you expected, using **macros**. Macros work by transforming the source code, and therefore any `set!` procedures in a macro avoid the problem of creating an intermediate binding.

I have also changed some of the forms to return a value, which is more Scheme-like.

The following remain unaltered:

```
(define (create-queue) '())
(define (getq q) (car q))
```

`addq!` is mainly unaltered, but renamed to `addq_`; it now returns the new queue:

```
(define (addq_ q obj)
  (if (or (null? q) (< obj (car q)))
      (cons obj q)
      (cons (car q) (addq_ (cdr q) obj))))
```

In order to make it work as expected, we create an `addq!` *macro*:

```
(define-syntax-rule (addq! q e)
  (begin
    (set! q (addq_ q e))
    q))
```

`remq!` is simply transformed into a *macro*:

```
(define-syntax-rule (remq! q)
  (begin
    (set! q (cdr q))
    q))
```

and here's how it works:

```
(define qq (create-queue))
(addq! qq 2)
=> '(2)
(addq! qq 1)
=> '(1 2)
(addq! qq 3)
=> '(1 2 3)
(remq! qq)
=> '(2 3)
(getq qq)
2
```

and if you look in Racket's macroexpander, this

```
(addq! qq 2)
(addq! qq 1)
(addq! qq 3)
(remq! qq)
(getq qq)
```

is transformed to:

```
(begin (set! qq (addq_ qq 2)) qq)
(begin (set! qq (addq_ qq 1)) qq)
(begin (set! qq (addq_ qq 3)) qq)
(begin (set! qq (cdr qq)) qq)
(getq qq)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked and was quite helpful.

Comment: Wouldn't this have problems with multiple evaluation?  More importantly, it will have problems if you use it with forms other than lexical variables.  E.g., If you had a list of queues and wanted to `remq!` from the first, you might try `(remq! (car list-of-queues))`, but that won't work, because you can't do `(set! (car list-of-queues) ...)` because `set!` is only for lexical variables, which `(car list-of-queues)` isn't.

Comment: As an analogue, consider what it would mean to define `set-car!` in a similar way;  the only thing it'd be doing is assigning a _new cons cell_ with a different car to lexical variables whose previous values were also a cons cell.  That's not what `set-car!` is supposed to do, though.  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16735050/1281433) describes how to implement a `set-value!` procedure for a mutable value cell.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor My point here was to show the OP how to implement what he was trying to do, and give a small introduction to macros. I'm confident he wasn't after implementating *places* in Scheme, that would have been overkill, don't you think?

Comment: A full implementation of places would certain have been overkill, yes.  I _do_ think that getting new users used to macros _is_ a good idea;  it's one of the strong points of the Lisp family.  However, you can't use this macro to add to an arbitrary queue (e.g., `(remq! (car list-of-queues))`) because it `remq!` only works with lexical variables, because its expansion contains `(set! …)`.  Now, I'll partially retract my earlier comment about multiple evaluation, because due to the fact that this only works with lexical variables and (to my knowledge) Scheme doesn't have any symbol-macros, the…

Comment: …only thing that would be multiply evaluated is a lexical variable, and there's not really any danger in that.  However, this _pattern_ of taking `qq` as an argument and using it multiple places in the expansion will, typically, lead to multiple evaluation issues.  E.g., since `addq!` now returns the queue, so (if it weren't for the lexical variable restriction) you'd be able to write `(addq! (addq! q 1) 2)` to add `1` and `2` to the queue.  Except that the expansion would contain `(addq! q 1)` twice, and you'd have added _three_ values to the queue instead of _two_.

Answer (score 3):

`set!` changes mutates the most local binding of a symbol. It does not change it's target.

```
(define  (addq! q obj)
    (if (or (null? q) (< obj (car q)))
        (set! q (cons obj q))
        (set! q (cons (car q) (addq! q obj))))) ; there is an error here

(addq! queue 'test)
```

So in both branches this procedure mutates what `q` is, but it does not change what `queue` is. When `q` cease to exist at the end of the procedure the procedure has accomplished nothing. Two ways to fix this is:

```
;; one that returns the new queue
(define  (addq q obj)
    (if (or (null? q) (< obj (car q)))
        (cons obj q)
        (cons (car q) (addq q obj)))) ; there is still an error here!
```

What you can do is have a queue head. Perhaps `(cons 'queue '())`. THen you can use the pair-mutator `set-cdr!` to mutate the queue. The head is so that you can always add to the front without having to worry about bindings to the queue (which would bind to the head).

Answer (score 2):

`set! q …` inside your `addq!` definition changes the value of the ***internal*** identifier `q`. You should *return* its value, and then grab hold of the returned value in your user code.

But your `addq!` function returns no usable value.

In other words, there's no need to use `set!` at all, just return the result of calling the appropriate `cons …`. This way your queue is ***persistent*** — having newer, updated queue does not invalidate its previous copies that you may have lying around.

Usually in Scheme, the bang `!` in a function's name indicates that that function works by mutating the structure it gets as an argument (i.e. through `set-car!` or `set-cdr!`). But doing this to create a new, updated copy of the queue will invalidate the old copies.

If you're absolutely sure you will only have the most recent copy of your queue, you still can't write it as you show, because `set!` will change the *internal* identifier, as I said above.

The way *around* it is to have a ***structure*** and use structure-mutating primitives. Simply, use a *tagged* list for your queues; then you can use `set-cdr!` on its *contents* — because Scheme argument passing is "by pointer value" (or is it "by value pointer"?) - the pointer is copied, but the copied pointer still points at the same place:

```
(define (make-empty-queue) (list 'queue))
(define (is-queue-empty? q) (null? (cdr q)))
```

Now you don't need to return any values, just as you didn't want to in the first place:

```
(define (addq! q x)
  (if (or (is-queue-empty? q) (< x (cadr q)))
    (set-cdr! q (cons x (cdr q)))
    (addq! (cdr q) x)))
```

That's a bit “dirty” because subsequent invocations of `addq!` won't receive a queue as a tagged list, with the `QUEUE` tag; though it will still work, as it only needs the `cdr` field of the structure. But, to be nice, better to make it an internal definition, to encapsulate the uncleanliness:

```
(define (addq! q x)
  (let g ((q q))
    (if (or (is-queue-empty? q) (< x (cadr q)))
      (set-cdr! q (cons x (cdr q)))
      (g (cdr q)))))
```

The remaining routines are changed accordingly:

```
(define (getq q)            ; no bang
  (if (is-queue-empty? q)
    (error " Empty Queue ") 
    (cadr q)))

(define (remq! q) 
  (if (is-queue-empty? q)
    (error " Empty Queue ") ; or make it some no-op like #f
    (set-cdr! q (cddr q))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I liked the tag list idea, another way it to implement queues and have set! work is as objects with local state

```
(define (create-queue)
 (let ((q '()))
   (define  (addq! obj)
     (if (null? q)
         (set! q (cons obj q))
         (let loop ((sub-q q))
           (cond ((< obj (car sub-q))
                  (let ((temp (cons (car sub-q) (cdr sub-q))))
                     (begin (set-cdr! sub-q temp)
                            (set-car! sub-q obj))))
                 ((null? (cdr sub-q))
                  (let ((temp (cons obj '())))
                     (set-cdr! sub-q temp)))
                 (else (loop (cdr sub-q))))))) 
         ;;this lets you avoid setting every cons cell up to the place 
         ;;the ojbect is inserted as the overhead cost of one cons cell  
   (define getq ;;doesn't need a bang, doesn't change any data
     (lambda ()
        (car q)))
    (define remq!
     (lambda ()
      (let ((temp (cdr q)))
       (set! q temp))))
    (define (dispatch message)
      (cond ((eq? message 'add) addq!)
            ((eq? message 'get) getq)
            ((eq? message 'rem) remq!)
            (else "error operation not defined for queue" message)))
   dispatch))

(define (addq! q-obj obj)
 ((q-obj 'add) obj))

(define (getq q-obj)
 ((q-obj 'get)))

(define (remq! q-obj)
 ((q-obj 'rem)))
```

```
(define test-queue (create-queue))
;Value: test-queue

(addq! test-queue 5)
;Value: ()

(getq test-queue)
;Value: 5

(addq! test-queue 8)

(addq! test-queue 7)

(getq test-queue)
;Value: 5

(remq! test-queue)

(getq test-queue)
;Value: 7

(remq! test-queue)


(getq test-queue)
;Value: 8

(addq! test-queue 2)

(getq test-queue)
;Value: 2
```

Comment: I was going to post something similar to this (using local state to record the item list), sort of similar to the answer to [How is set! defined in scheme?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16733472/1281433).  I'm glad to see someone beat me to it!  You can do the insertion without a temporary cons, though, and still have only one assignment: http://pastebin.com/CzaXhtmy .

Answer (score 0):

The `set!` syntactic form changes the object **referenced** by `q` but, importantly, the return value of `set!` is undefined.  Thus each of your `set!` expressions return something undefined, your `if` returns something undefined and your `addq!` returns undefined.

Although I won't promise it works, an improvement to your code would be:

```
(define (addq q obj)
  (if (or (null? q) (< obj (car q)))
      (set! q (cons obj q))
      (set! q (cons (car q) (addq q obj))))
  q) ; return the newly set q
```

Or, more idiomatically,

```
(define (addq q obj)
  (if (or (null? q) (< obj (car q)))
      (cons obj q)
      (cons (car q) (addq q obj))))
```

Notice I renamed your function to `addq` because it doesn't modify the passed in `q`; it returns an extended on.

If you want to modify the queue, rather then extend it, then think about rewriting `create-queue` as:

```
(define (create-queue) (cons 'QUEUE '()))
```

and then have your `addq!` procedure use `set-cdr!` on the value returned by the above `create-queue`.  Like this:

```
(define (queue? obj) (and (pair? obj) (eq? 'QUEUE (car obj))))

(define (addq! q obj)
  (assert (queue? q))
  (if (or (null? q) (< obj (car q)))
      (set-cdr! q (cons obj q))
      (set-cdr! q (cons (car q) (addq! q obj)))) ; no guarantee this works...
  q)
```

Comment: with `(define x (list 1 2 3 4))`, `x` is **referenced** by `q` in `(addq! x 0)`, but `(set! q ...)` won't change it.

Answer (score 0):

Scheme only has **pass-by-value**. This means that when you pass a variable to a function, no matter what the function does, it cannot cause an assignment (i.e. `set!`) to the variable in the calling scope.

The `q` inside `addq!` is a local variable. Assigning to it (`set!`) has no effect on the outside.